# Dapper get error when Join between tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dapper, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm new to dapper i get error when i retrieve data from joined table

```
var qry = @"SELECT Cities.Id,
                           Cities.Name,
                           Cities.Sort,
                           Countries.Name
                           FROM[dbo].[Cities]
                            JOIN Countries ON Countries.Id = Cities.CountryId";

var result = con.Query<Cities, Countries>(qry);
```

this is the error message

> 'SqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Query' and no
>   extension method 'Query' accepting a first argument of type
>   'SqlConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

[Error Image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-fL9oThC3TUWWRzeS1IX3I1cHc)

Comment: Are you sure you added Dapper as reference to your project?

Comment: Either Dapper is not referenced at all or you miss `using Dapper` at the top of the source file.

Comment: yes i added this statement (using Dapper;)

Comment: I believe then there is no overload of `Query` that accepts **two** generic type arguments and a string query. The one that exists requires a map from two types to one.

Comment: @wiktorZychla There is [multi-mapping](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping) support . And if not, there'd be a different exception.

Comment: @stefankmitph: too bad you haven't really verified what you wrote. This is exactly the compilation error you get trying to call the method with two generic arguments.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Sorry mate, you're right of course.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by invalid invocation - there is no overload that accepts **two** generic arguments.

Event though Dapper supports multimapping, the call actually requires three generic arguments, `TFirst`, `TSecond` and `TReturn` (where `TReturn` can be one of the two or yet another type).

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping

An example valid call from the docs

```
var data = connection.Query<Post, User, Post>(sql, (post, user) => { post.Owner = user; return post;});
```

An invalid invocation with only two generic arguments yields exactly the error message you get.

My guess is you either wanted the 3rd overload that accepts a single generic argument

```
 Query<TResult>( string sql, Type[] types, Func<object[], TResult> map, ... );
```

or the 4th one that accepts three

```
 Query<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>( string sql, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> map, ... );
```

In both cases you still need a map function.